# How to add website certificates to a Linux Docker container for a Python webscraper?

Tags: python, linux, docker, web-scraping, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to set up a docker container with a scraper inside written in Python. When I deploy this container it gives me the warning that the website certificates aren't available. When I check the certificates those are indeed not inside the docker. I have this problem with multiple websites but 2 examples are Let's Encrypt and Cloudflare.

As you can see at the bottom I've commented out some stuff that I tried using to install the certificates. But the docker container won't install the web certificates in the docker container such that I can use them from my python script.

If the question is unclear or I need to put out more information I'm happy to help.

Thank you in advance.

The Docker Code:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 
COPY requirements.txt.
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
WORKDIR /app
COPY *
ENV HTTP_PROXY="http://*.*.*.*:****" HTTPS_PROXY="https://*.*.*.*:****"

# # Set the certificates
# RUN apt-get update \
#     && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
#     ca-certificates

# # ADD sni-cloudflaressl-com.pem site1.pem /app/files/certificates/
# ADD files/certificates/sni-cloudflaressl-com.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/sni-

cloudflaressl-com.pem


# #openssl x509 checks the certificate
# RUN cd /usr/local/share/ca-certificates \
#     && openssl x509 -in /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/site1.pem -inform PEM -out site1.crt \ 
#     && openssl x509 -in /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/sni-cloudflaressl-com.pem -inform PEM -out sni-cloudflaressl-com.crt \
#     && update-ca-certificates

RUN useradd appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

# During debugging, this entry point will be overridden. For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-debug
CMD ["/bin/bash", "mainSh.sh"]
```

Ps: I know the Docker starts a bash shell and not a python program but I use this to run Python in a certain way.

Comment: You haven't provided us with enough information to reproduce the problem. Can you give us an example of a website URL that results in certificate errors?

Comment: Thank you for responding. For example, Stackoverflow because the Docker container does not have the Let's Encrypt certificate. Another example would be https://www.huurwoningen.nl/ which has a CloudFlare certificate.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. If I start a `python:3.8-slim-buster` container, `pip install requests`, and then `requests.get('https://www.huurwoningen.nl/')` or `requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com')`, it works without any errors.